# eclipse source folder is not java project, after importing project from git

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I have imported project from git and after that converted that into a maven project.

but while trying to add any class or package in my source folder I am getting an error  **source folder is not java project**  and also ctrl+space is not working.

I have also tried in my repo **mvn eclipse:eclipse** but that also hasn't worked.

Comment: Do not use eclipse:eclipse.  Instead clone with git from command and import existing sources as Maven project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `mvn eclipse:eclipse` does not work, you can try and [specify manually the src folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27795020/6309), which will be recorded in the .project.

Check first if ["Convert to Faceted Form" / Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952602/6309) would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already specified the src folder and it's not working, try right-clicking on project -> maven->Update Project...

Then check 'force update of snapshots/releases' box and click ok.

This should clear any problems resulting from old branches in eclipse.